# Fix a lookup type site column when website is provisioned

Tags: lookup-column

The site column "Related Task" is lookup type. I would like to fix this column's "Get information from" table. The get information table is within the same site. Is it possible to fix this using using object model?

Comment: Looks like you were able to figure out the answer to your question. Could you move the comment to be an answer instead?

Comment: I accidentally deleted your comment! Sorry! Do you have the code handy still?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix...

```
private static void FixLookupField(SPWeb web, SPList spList, string strTargetList, string strTargetField, string strLookupFieldName)
        {
            SPList targetList = web.Lists[strTargetList];
            SPField targetField = targetList.Fields[strTargetField];
            SPFieldLookup lkp = (SPFieldLookup)spList.Fields[strLookupFieldName];
            lkp.LookupField = targetField.InternalName;
            lkp.Update();
        }
```