# Is it possible to create an automatic connection between the look up field and another column?

Tags: lookup-column

Im struggling with a problem in SharePoint 2013.

I have one list with procedure codes, which includes the “procedure code” plus some other fields
 In another table, i have volume data related to procedure code.
  If i in addition to the “procedure code” column in the procedure code list ad a “look-up” field, i can join the data from the two tables in an elegant way. The disadvantage is that the “look-up” field manually have to have the procedure code added there to show the corresponding data.

Is it possible / complicated to make this automatic?

Comment: You mean when a new item is created, it should pick the lookup field automatically? so the lookup list only have 1 item or am I missing something?

Comment: the thing is that i have so many things to add, and it would take me so much time if i had to do that. And save so much time if it was possible. I have two lists, one with the lookup field that take a value from the other list. But can i do this automatic?

Comment: you might need to write script, either powershell or using client object model.. It isn't possible Out of the box.. One way is Import Spreadsheet as a List.. But that will not place values in two lists and use as lookup..

Comment: okej. So you´re that the only way is to write a script with powershell or using client object model? It doesnt have some settings inside SharePoint or it just with script?

Comment: AFAIK, no there isn't any setting.. but wait for other experts to look at the question and maybe they can suggest something..

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like:

```
// Re-bind the lookup column if necessary
                SPFieldLookup lookUp = (SPFieldLookup)taskList.Fields.GetField("RI Item");
                // if the lookup column is looking for a list that no longer exists
                if (!lookUp.LookupList.Equals(riList.ID))
                {
                    // Re-bind it by updating the schema xml of the column
                    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                    xml.LoadXml(lookUp.SchemaXml);
                    XmlAttribute attr = xml.CreateAttribute("List");
                    attr.Value = riList.ID.ToString("B");
                    xml.DocumentElement.SetAttributeNode(attr);

                    lookUp.SchemaXml = xml.InnerXml;
                    lookUp.Update();
                }
```

Related Links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5c421a2-ca88-414e-9110-2b8ecb716e54/reattach-a-sharepoint-list-lookup-column-to-the-source-list?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

[Fix a lookup type site column when website is provisioned](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13191/fix-a-lookup-type-site-column-when-website-is-provisioned)

http://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/How-to-define-a-LookupField-referencing-list-in-another-web.aspx

Comment: Please mark as answer if it worked for you. Thanks!